# GAE unsubscribe from a user's presence

Tags: python, google-app-engine, xmpp

Is there a way to unsubscribe from a user's presence? I no longer want to receive updates on /_ah/xmpp/presence/... for a particular user. I can't seem to find a simple API call to do that.

After digging around the XMPP protocol I found [this](http://xmpp.org/rfcs/rfc3921.html#rfc.section.2.2.1) which seems to indicate that doing a send_presence with presence type of 'unsubscribe' should work. Unfortunately digging into the GAE's xmpp API it appears that it defines

```
_VALID_PRESENCE_TYPES = frozenset([PRESENCE_TYPE_AVAILABLE,
                               PRESENCE_TYPE_UNAVAILABLE,
                               PRESENCE_TYPE_PROBE])
```

Which means I can't even do a `send_presence(user_to_remove, status="", presence_type="unsubscribe")` (PRESENCE_TYPE_AVAILABLE and others are just strings like "available" as per the xmpp specificiation)

Has anyone come across this issue or know how to achieve this ?

Answer (score 3):

It seems that you can't. [The docs](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/xmpp/functions.html) (and the docstring) confirm that presence_type accepts a subset of the types defined in  RFC 3921.

You can submit this as a feature request to [the issue tracker](http://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/list).

Answer (score 2):

As an experiment, you could re-implement your own "send_presence" that does the same thing as the existing function, without the check for valid presence types. Not officially sanctioned but worth a try.

One thing to note is that this won't *block* clients from re-subscribing from your bot or from badly-behaved clients ignoring it.

And as Drew mentioned, please do submit an issue on the issue tracker.

Comment: @Moise - Sorry for the delay, I'm traveling in an area with spotty internet connectivity. I will be trying this today and post an update